# Getting strange result querying carts when using multiple search filter groups

Tags: magento2, cart, api, search

On Magento 2.0.6 community
Using multiple filters to perform an AND operation, I'm getting very unexpected results.

Reproducable steps:

**1)** Successful GET call to search for abandoned carts with a simple 1 filter group (updated_at greater than equal 2016-06-14):

### .../rest/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-06-14&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq

Result of Step 1:
Assumed result is correct, it fetched 6 carts (3 Active, 3 InActive).

{"items":[
        {"id":384,"created_at":"2016-06-14 02:50:16","updated_at":"2016-06-14 02:59:30","is_active":true,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":2,"customer":{"email":null,"firstname":null,"lastname":null},"billing_address":{"id":787,"region":"Ohio","region_id":47,"region_code":"OH","country_id":"US","street":["1880 Quail Nest Ct"],"telephone":"317-496-4113","postcode":"45373","city":"Troy","firstname":"j","lastname":"c","email":null,"same_as_billing":0,"save_in_address_book":0},"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":3,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":387,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:38:10","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:44:25","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":793,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":388,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:45:24","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:46:23","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":795,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":389,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:46:58","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:13","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":797,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":390,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:50:00","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:53:30","is_active":true,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":2,"customer":{"email":null,"firstname":null,"lastname":null},"billing_address":{"id":799,"region":"Alaska","region_id":2,"region_code":"AK","country_id":"US","street":["test"],"telephone":"1234567890","postcode":"35008","city":"test","firstname":"test","lastname":"test","email":null,"same_as_billing":0,"save_in_address_book":0},"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":3,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":391,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:53:54","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:59:20","is_active":true,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"email":null,"firstname":null,"lastname":null},"billing_address":{"id":801,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","email":null,"same_as_billing":0,"save_in_address_book":0},"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":3,"store_id":1}
        ]
,"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"updated_at","value":"2016-06-14","condition_type":"gteq"}]}]},"total_count":6}

**------------**
**2)** Performing a second query, adding an additional filter to narrow down the result (+ is_active equals true)

### .../rest/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-06-14&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=is_active&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=true&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

Result of Step 2:
Although POST transaction was successful, it fetched the exact opposite of what's expected, it returned the 3 carts whose is_active flags are false.

{"items":[
        {"id":387,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:38:10","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:44:25","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":793,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":388,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:45:24","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:46:23","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":795,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":389,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:46:58","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:13","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":797,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ]
,"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"updated_at","value":"2016-06-14","condition_type":"gteq"}]},{"filters":[{"field":"is_active","value":"true","condition_type":"eq"}]}]},"total_count":3}

**------------**
**3)** Changing the is_active filter value from true to false yielded the same 3 records whose is_active flags are FALSE (presumably generating a set of correct results).

{"items":[
        {"id":387,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:38:10","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:44:25","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":793,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":388,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:45:24","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:46:23","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":795,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ,{"id":389,"created_at":"2016-06-14 11:46:58","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:13","is_active":false,"is_virtual":false,"items_count":1,"items_qty":1,"customer":{"id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2016-02-09 14:49:42","updated_at":"2016-06-14 11:49:33","created_in":"Default Store View","email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","gender":1,"store_id":1,"website_id":1,"addresses":[{"id":1,"customer_id":1,"region":{"region_code":"IN","region":"Indiana","region_id":24},"region_id":24,"country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green"}],"disable_auto_group_change":0},"billing_address":{"id":797,"region":"Indiana","region_id":24,"region_code":"IN","country_id":"US","street":["619 Hummingbird Dr"],"telephone":"317-695-2566","postcode":"46112-7453","city":"Brownsburg","firstname":"Andy","lastname":"Green","customer_id":1,"email":"andy@vergecommerce.com","same_as_billing":0,"customer_address_id":1,"save_in_address_book":0},"reserved_order_id":0,"orig_order_id":0,"currency":{"global_currency_code":"USD","base_currency_code":"USD","store_currency_code":"USD","quote_currency_code":"USD","store_to_base_rate":0,"store_to_quote_rate":0,"base_to_global_rate":1,"base_to_quote_rate":1},"customer_is_guest":false,"customer_note_notify":true,"customer_tax_class_id":4,"store_id":1}
        ]
,"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"updated_at","value":"2016-06-14","condition_type":"gteq"}]},{"filters":[{"field":"is_active","value":"false","condition_type":"eq"}]}]},"total_count":3}

---

Why did the the additional filter condition **is_active eq true** generate the wrong set of results?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me try to summarize, when performing a search query for carts using a single filter condition "updated_at >= 2016-06-17".  It returns 5 carts, 2 active, 3 Inactive.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that you have encountered a bug that is similar to what has already been reported here as [Repository Filter Groups Applied Inconsistently](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4287). I notice you have already reported your details as an [issue on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5030) as well. The code that should sort carts can be found in the `getList` method from the `QuoteRepository` [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.6/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php).

Comment: That could be Kristoff.  And, yes, I re-posted the question on stackexchange to see if anyone else has run into the issue.

Comment: In my follow-up posting (summary description), it seems that there is a bug when M2 is applying those multiple filters, period.